# Error while using a hook useNavigate, "useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an issue with React Router in my React application. I have a component where I'm using the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom` to navigate users based on certain conditions and  consistently getting the error message:

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a `<Router>` component.

I have made sure that  the component where `useNavigate` is used is wrapped within the `Router` component.

My code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    if (user) {
      navigate('/chats');
    }
  }, [navigate]);

  return (
    <Container maxW = 'xl' centerContent >
      <Box
        d='flex'
        justifyContent='center'
        p={3}
        bg={"white"}
        w='100%'
        m="40px 0 15px 0"
        borderRadius="lg"
        borderWidth="1px"
      >
        <Text fontSize="3xl" fontWeight="600" fontFamily="Work sans" color="black" textAlign="center">
          Chatter Box
        </Text>
      </Box>
      <Box bg="white" w="100%" p={4} borderRadius="lg" borderWidth="1px">
        <Tabs variant='soft-rounded'>
          <TabList mb="1em">
            <Tab width="50%">Login</Tab>
            <Tab width="50%">Sign Up</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <TabPanels>
            <TabPanel>
              <Login />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel>
            <Signup />
            </TabPanel>
          </TabPanels>
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

In my App.js file, I've wrapped the `HomePage` component within the `Router` component as well.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import ChatPage from './pages/ChatPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/chats" element={<ChatPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expected the navigation to work properly without any errors.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you have shared here. See if completely restarting the development server resolves this. Or delete the `node_modules` directory, re-run `npm install` and restart the project.